# Some questions about SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need a help about this questions in SQL Oracle :

Question1 about Hierarchical retrieved:
[image]
I think that the response is D and E :

```
Select * from Employees
Start With Employee_ID=100
Connect By PRIOR Employee_ID=Manager_ID;
```

Without add the Where clause !

Question 2 about synonyms :
[image]
I think that the response is D.

Question 3 about indexes :
[image]
I think that the response is D.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The result of your query would include employee 100, who presumably doesn't report to themselves - the question is only looking for people under them. You could use a where clause to exclude that user. (The data shown doesn't have an employee 100; but may just be a subset of the data.)
2. The green highlighting suggests the question setter agrees with you that D is correct; but you seem to have chosen B. Which would also work, but **only** if OE had the `create public synonym` system privilege, which hasn't been stated. OE wouldn't be able to do that by default.
3. For D the `list_price > 1000` condition cannot be evaluated using that index. It's feasible there could be an index on list price and Oracle would use *both* indexes, but much more likely it would use a full table scan. For C the index can be used to check both the values - you can think of it as `(UPPER(product_name) = 'LASERPRO' OR UPPER(product_name) = 'Cable')`. It can't match Cable of course, as that is mixed case not all uppercase, but that doesn't prevent the index being used to *try* to find a match.